# Temporary IPTable Rules when Process Runs

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

Struggling to find the solution for this and maybe it's easier than I'm making it out to be.

I need to open ports in the firewall when a process runs. That process could be requesting the usage of a range of ports, lets say 5000 to 5500. Is there a secure way to go about doing this? If not what is the most secure way to go about doing it?

Comment: You want to open ports only when the process in the port range 5000-5500 runs right? Can you please elaborate the requirement.

Comment: Correct, in this specific case it's a server that runs on demand.

Perhaps I'm worried about nothing and I could just leave a range of ports open but that doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Are these ports for inbound or outbound traffic?

Comment: Technically both, the server both sends and receives data from clients.